# how to solve non-linear pde in two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Assuming that $F(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$ what is the solution of
the following partial differential equation?
\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right) + xy = C
\end{equation}
Here, $C$ is a constant.

Is there a general scheme to solve such PDEs? It would be appreciated if such scheme is provided, since I need to solve more such PDEs. For instance, how to solve the following PDE?
\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right) + xy + \gamma x\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = C'
\end{equation}